# How to share Text, Link and image using FacebookSDK in Swift 3

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3

I am trying to share content in facebook using iOS facebook SDK in swift3.
I already installed pod in my xXode project and linked to facebook developer and all setting in .plist file but it does not work for me.

This is the three pod that I have installed:

```
1. pod 'FacebookCore'
2. pod 'FacebookLogin'
3. pod 'FacebookShare'
```

Facebook login button proper work but sharing in facebook don't.

This is the code i have used:

```
var content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://newsroom.fb.com/")!,
                                   title: "Name: Facebook News Room",
                                   description: "Description: The Facebook Swift SDK helps you develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.",
                                   imageURL: URL(string: "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png"))


    content.placeId = "166793820034304"

    showShareDialog(content, mode: .web)
```

Comment: can you show us the code, how do you prepare the content to be shared?

Comment: ya sure i updated my question

Comment: have you done all `Prerequisites`  stated on the developer portal?

Comment: are you trying to do it on the simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: i was tried to facebook login button this are proper working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132382/discussion-between-nilesh-parmar-and-dirtydanee).

Answer (score 2):

Import Social

```
let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
vc?.add(UIImage.image)

vc?.add(URL(string: "http://www.example.com/"))

vc?.setInitialText("Initial text here.")

self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: SLComposeViewController was deprecated in IOS 11

Answer (score 0):

SLComposeViewController have been deprecated in IOS 11. See more details here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/social_constants

Now You can use FBSDKShareKit for the sharing function on facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/